# PHP mail send from noreply@domail.com

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I want to send email to users who click on forgot password link on my website from no-reply@mycompanmysname.com.

I am able to send mail through my companys mail server but I do not want my companys email address to be displayed.
Can anybody suggest how is that done?

I am using phpmailer and this is my code:

```
$from = "companyname@yahoo.com";
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$body             = $messageBody;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; //added
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
//$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                                                  
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
$mail->Host       = "smtp server name";    
$mail->Port       = 587;                   
$mail->Username   = "********"; 
$mail->Password   = "******";           
$mail->From("$name");
//$mail->SetFrom("$from");


$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$mail->AddAddress("$toEmail");
$mail->Subject = "".$subject."";$mail->Body = $headers . "<br>" . $messageBody . "<br>" . $confidential;
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->MsgHTML($mail->Body);

if(!$mail->Send()) {

    //echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    print "<p class='Error'>Error in sending email.Please try again.</p>";

} else {
    print "<p class='success'>An email is sent to you with the access information.</p>";

}
```

Comment: Which mail address do you WANT to be displayed?

Comment: What do you mean *not displayed*? All mails have a "from" attribute, those that don't would likely end up in a spam-filter.

Comment: I want the users to get email from 'no-reply@mycompanyname.com' email address and not from 'companyname@yahoo.com'.

Comment: Yahoo doesn't generally allow this - if you're sending through a yahoo account, it will require a yahoo from address. Gmail does the same.

Answer (score 0):

Taking an example from [their docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), you can do something like this:

```
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');
//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');
```

From personal experience, you can do this and it works, but in some mail clients, such as Gmail, you'll get something along the lines of `From: email@website.com via otherdomain.com`. I'm not sure if there's a way outside of this other than adding some DNS settings. Not sure if you have access to that.

Comment: Is there way to mask the email address from where its actually sent and display 'noreply@..' address in that place

Comment: Like I said, `addReplyTo()` works, but some clients show the actual domain or server it gets sent from

Comment: That just assigns the replyto email address. It doesnt change the from address

Comment: Yeah, that's what `setFrom()` is for

Comment: yes i know that and I am able to send mail by email address mentioned in setFrom() but I want the user to see the email from 'noreply' email address instead of that mentioned in setFrom

Comment: Any reason it would need to be different? Why not set the noreply address initially?